# Load Popup Message in Same Page, Different HTML Content using multiple image click

Tags: javascript, html, popup

```
<a href="style1.html" onClick="return popup(this, 'notes')"><img id="myImg1" class="myImgClass1" src="images/1.jpg"></a>

<a href="style2.html" onClick="return popup(this, 'notes')"><img id="myImg2" class="myImgClass2" src="images/2.jpg"></a>

<a href="style3.html" onClick="return popup(this, 'notes')"><img id="myImg3" class="myImgClass3" src="images/3.jpg"></a>


<a href="style4.html" onClick="return popup(this, 'notes')"><img id="myImg4" class="myImgClass4"
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript"> </script>

    <a href="style1.html" onClick="return popup(this, 'notes')"><img id="myImg1" class="myImgClass1" src="images/1.jpg"></a>

    <a href="style2.html" onClick="return popup(this, 'notes')"><img id="myImg2" class="myImgClass2" src="images/2.jpg"></a>

    <a href="style3.html" onClick="return popup(this, 'notes')"><img id="myImg3" class="myImgClass3" src="images/3.jpg"></a>


    <a href="style4.html" onClick="return popup(this, 'notes')"><img id="myImg4" class="myImgClass4" src="images/4.jpg"></a>

      
<!--Hidden Popup html content -->
      <div id="style1">HTML CONTENT 1 HERE </div>
      <div id="style2">HTML CONTENT 2 HERE </div>
      <div id="style3">HTML CONTENT 3 HERE </div>
      <div id="style4">HTML CONTENT 4 HERE </div>
```

I have searched and can't find a solution.  Onclick 'myImg1' id I would like to load html content from 'style1' id in same window

Onclick 'myImg2' id I would like to load html content from 'style2' id in same window.

Style 1 to 4 div should be hidden and only load via popup. I am also struggling to have a popup close button.

Comment: could you re edit your question and make your code separate from your question so that we could help you.

Comment: I have updated the question. Just want onClick image1 opens popup Style1 html content and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to do but is this what you want. you can run the code snippet and look at the result.

```js
function popup(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#a,#b,#c {
  display:none;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<a onclick="popup('a')">FIrst</a>
<a onclick="popup('b')">Second</a>
<a onclick="popup('c')">Third</a>

<div id='a' href='#'>This is 1st</div>
<div id='b' href='#'>This is 2nd</div>
<div id='c' href='#'>This is 3rd</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I am trying to solve. 'First', 'Second', 'Third' needs to open in ONE pop up window and a 'x' to close the popup please.  All 3 of them can not open at the same time. Thank you.